# JAXB2 unmarshalling xsd:anyType Error

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I am encountering a problem unmarshalling data containing xsd:anyType(ur-type) objects such as:

```
    <xsd:element name="Options" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Key" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="Next" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
```

JAXB2 creates the following Java class for the element above;

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "key",
    "next"
})
public static class Options {

    @XmlElement(name = "Key")
    protected Object key;
    @XmlElement(name = "Next")
    protected Object next;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the key property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public Object getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the key property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setKey(Object value) {
        this.key = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the next property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public Object getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the next property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Object }
     *     
     */
    public void setNext(Object value) {
        this.next = value;
    }
}
```

The marshalling works but when unmarshalling, it throws the following exception;

```
    org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.checkNamespaceWF(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.setName(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.createElementNS(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.utils.DOMBuilder.startElement(DOMBuilder.java:322)
        at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1072)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:118)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:73)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:455)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:433)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:71)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:137)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:240)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:277)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:246)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:277)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:246)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:277)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:246)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:123)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:314)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:297)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:107)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:581)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:568)
...
```

I am using;

```
JDK 1.6.0_19
spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.xalan-2.7.0.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.xerces-2.8.1.jar
```

Thanks,

Henry Kim

Comment: You don't need to include the JAXB JARs, it's already included with Java6.

Comment: This could potentially be a Metro JAXB bug.  Have you tried another JAXB impl such as EclipseLink MOXy JAXB (I'm the tech lead):  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/Spring

Comment: Hi, did you get to resolve the issue ?